# Intent In Parent Class From Child Class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context, navigation-drawer

from [here](https://gist.github.com/anandbose/7d6efb35c900eaba3b26) i'm getting easiest way to reuse a common Navigation drawer among a group of activities. but the problem is I cant move from one activity to another activity.

I'm using intent to move from activity to another activity,
but, this i'm creating this intent in parent class, I call it AppBaseActivity.java

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.category:{
            Intent category = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(category);
        }
        case R.id.product:{
            Intent product = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(product);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I extend CategoryActivity and ProductActivity to AppBaseActivity

how can I use intent for moving from CategoryActivity to ProductActivity

or

from ProductActivity to CategoryActivity

Comment: I don't think Navigation Drawer is intended to be used with `Activities`, since if you start another one, he won't be part of the new one. Sounds like an odd implementation for me.. Also, did you try using `getActivity()` instead of AppContext ?

Comment: Searched about it a bit, take a look here [here](https://gist.github.com/libinbensin/613dea436302d3015563)

Comment: I try use getActivity(), but showing error = cannot resolve method getActivity()

Comment: From which class are you calling this code snippet ?

Comment: this snippet in AppBaseActivity.java
and my CategoryActivity extends on AppBaseActivity.

Comment: Solved.
thanks very much for helping me

Comment: you can also use this library for easy implementation https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator